# How to cut-and-paste - using right click - on all Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs, cut-and-paste

In *Google Docs,* some documents would allow `cut-and-paste` using right click and choosing from a menu, while other documents insist that one use <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-V</kbd>, et al.

Is there a way to force a *Google Docs* document to use `cut-and-paste` commands from a menu?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the browser and [changes Google has made to the interface](https://www.usatoday.com/story/tech/columnist/2014/04/13/copy-and-paste-in-google-docs/7568661/). In Firefox, a [configuration change](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1196485) may allow copy, cut and paste to work, unless a document is locked, of course.

- In the URL bar, enter `about:config`.
- If this is the first time you've done this, click to acknowledge that this might, "void your warranty".
- In the search bar, type `clipboardev`.
- If `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` is set to `false`, double-click it to set it to `true`.

**Caveat:** On some web sites, the *converse* happens, where copy, cut and paste are *blocked* when `dom.event.clipboardevents.enabled` is set `true` (e.g. for [password entry](https://lifehacker.com/enable-copy-paste-in-web-pages-that-disallow-it-with-a-1601848114)), so make a note to yourself to set this back for those sites. sigh

Comment: It's not that cut-and-paste is not working, it does. It's just that on some Google Docs, one cannot use the cut-and-paste from a mouse right-click choice, but one has to use <Ctrl><C> and <Ctrl><Shift><V>. I wish to be able to use the cut-and-paste from a mouse right-click choice.